# NoSuchMethodError in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, nosuchmethoderror

I have a project of spark 2.1.0, it work on my local cluster(They are Ubuntu 16.04), But on the work cluster(Red Hat 4.4.7-4, Is so old) is error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.JsonWriter$.streaming(Ljava/io/Writer;Lorg/json4s/Formats;)Lorg/json4s/JsonWriter;
    at org.json4s.native.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:43)
    at org.json4s.native.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:37)
    at org.json4s.native.Json.write(Json.scala:11)
    at net.yunzone.OperSql$$anonfun$updateTypeStat$1.apply(OperSql.scala:315)
    at net.yunzone.OperSql$$anonfun$updateTypeStat$1.apply(OperSql.scala:299)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at net.yunzone.OperSql$.updateTypeStat(OperSql.scala:299)
    at net.yunzone.AnalysisLacci$.analysisLacci(AnalysisLacci.scala:62)
    at net.yunzone.UShanxi.AnalysisSource$.main(AnalysisSource.scala:203)
    at net.yunzone.UShanxi.AnalysisSource.main(AnalysisSource.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Begin i think they are problems of env or configuration，I checked them several times，It's still a mistake.I also try to replace json4s version to 3.4 or 3.3，It's still a mistake.

Is this likely to be related to the glibc version?

Who can help me, I'm almost crazy。

Comment: First check whether you are using multiple versions of the same jar   in your code base, if  it contains single version then probably spark it self using the same and the version is different then either remove it from your code or spark( requires rebuilding of spark).

Comment: create an uber-jar (a jar with dependencies)

Comment: I found the problem where the spark jars folder inside there are two versions of json4s exist, this is really an accident

Answer (score 0):

I think the **most likely case** in my experience:

You have some jar dependencies from dependency manage tool such as maven.

But when you test you code, you use jars in ~/.m2/... maybe in test scope.

**But the other cluster also have the different version of this dependency.**

you should use some extra plugin to package all you dependencies and your application code in **an uber jar**, and upload it on you driver node, and execute it.